# Paypal adaptive payments api pending status issue

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal adaptive payments api to send payment to my user on my website. when i am sending payments some status are pending. is there any paypal api or function which provide me after some days that pending status is completed or not. thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  It will POST transaction data to a listener script you have on your web server in real-time so you can automate tasks based on pending payments, completed payments, refunds, disputes, etc.

For PHP there are lots of IPN templates/classes available for you to use.  [Here's one](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template) that I built years ago that is still very useful.  There are good [options on Packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=paypal%20ipn) so you can easily load them up in Composer, too, if you'd rather go that route.

Comment: if i want to put your built in ipn in my site then can you please tell me step to follow. thanks

Comment: The [Install.txt](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template/blob/master/Install.txt) included with it provides instructions.  Let me know if you have any specific trouble with it.

Comment: how much time interval paypal send notification ?

Comment: It's generally pretty much instant.  It can be a little delayed sometimes, but it usually comes pretty quickly.